# How to add focus function in MediaRecorder?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

Device: HTC
Android: 2.3.5

I am programming a video recorder application using `MediaRecorder`.
It works but without focus function.

I can add focus function in the camera preview stage.
But once I click the button to start `MediaRecorder`, the focus loses.

I searched online, failing to find answers.

**[Update 1: with more details]**

I used `setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);` and `setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)`. 
But I investigate the HTC device (2.3.5 sdk version), it has no option for `FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO`.

Actually the innate video recording of the HTC device (2.3.5 sdk version) has the focus function during the preview stage and keeps the focus distance during video recording if I do not change the focus distance. If I change the focus distance, the recorded video is out of focus.

But for `MediaRecorder`, when I get a good focus at the preview stage, it will lose focus once the `MediaRecorder` is started.

Comment: Did you specify parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO); after opening your camera device where parameters = camera.getParameters(); ?

Comment: Thanks. I have set it (actually the sdk version 2.3.5 does not support the option). See [Update 1: with more details] in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar problem with focusing with MediaRecorder (particulalry on pre 3.0 versions of android). The following code of setting the parameterers explicitly solved my problem:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);

parameters.set("cam_mode", 1 ); //not sure why this arcane setting is required. found this in another post on Stackoverlflow 

mCamera.setParameters(parameters);  


mCamera.stopPreview();  // call this if you had started preview before or else recording wont work on Android versions <= 2.3

mediarecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
```

Also you have mentioned that you are seeing problems with HTC device. So it would be wise to try the above code on a non-HTC device too. I have faced some really wierd problems with HTC devices at many other places.